# Link to helper for a dynamic url path in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, link-to, view-helpers

I have the following code in my rails application,

```
<% = link_to variant.name, add_coaching_product_path(:variant => variant) %>
```

I want the above path `add_coaching_product_path` to send in a variable, and use in rails view.

I tried the following way, but it didn't work.

```
<% = link_to variant.name, "#{add_coaching_product_path}(:variant => #{variant})" %>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** `add_coaching_product_path` is kind of method created by Rails routes.

You can do it as below,

```
<% = link_to variant.name, send("add_coaching_product_path", { variant: variant }) %>
```

Instead of "add_coaching_product_path", you can pass dynamic path in form of string.